# harmful printk effect in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

Here is a part of my code.

```
for (i=0;i<29;i++) 
{

    *reg0= (unsigned int)(src[i][0]<<24 | (src[i][1]<<16) | (src[i][2]<<8) | src[i][3]);
    printk("");

    *reg4= (unsigned int)(src[i][4]<<24 | (src[i][5]<<16) | (src[i][6]<<8) | src[i][7]);
    printk("");

    *reg8= (unsigned int)(src[i][8]<<24 | (src[i][9]<<16) | (src[i][10]<<8) | src[i][11]);
    printk("");

    *reg12= (unsigned int)(src[i][12]<<24 | (src[i][13]<<16) | (src[i][14]<<8) | 0);
    printk("");

}
```

it is a for loop used in a module built under petalinux. it works very well after doing insmod and execution the user application. But when I comment `printk("")` the module doesn't work any more and it seems like it gets lost in recursion. I have to suppress printk becase it takes much time execution.

Any help would be appreciated.

regards.

Comment: Usually if the behavior changes when you add or remove a function call, it means you have undefined behavior somewhere.

Comment: What's the declaration of `src`?

Comment: This indicates a race condition in your code. Can't really tell anything else from the snippet here, but I would start by looking at how `src` is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your early response.

Comment: the declaration of src is 
static    unsigned int src[29][15];

Comment: and the declaration of *reg0, *reg4, *reg8 and *reg12 is volatile unsigned int

Comment: You may simplify your code by using proper `get_unaligned_le32()`/`get_unaligned_be32()` calls. And yes, you need to provide more context. I'm pretty sure you did a small mistake which makes a drastic change in behaviour.